# ui.bootstrap Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I am having trouble understanding why ui.bootstrap dependency injection is not working for me properly. When I inject the dependency, all the content in my single page all disappears. I am not receiving any sort of error in the console log. I feel like I did everything good, but I need a set of new eyes to see what is causing the problem.

```js
(function(){

'use strict';

angular.module('ghostApp',['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('GamesCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

   $scope.currentPage = 1;
   $scope.pageSize = 12;

   $http.get("json/games.json").success(function(data){
    $scope.games = data;
   });


  }]);

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ghostApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img class="navbar-brand" src="images/ghost.png"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/home/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/events/">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/games/">Games</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/media/">Media</a>
                    </li>                
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/about/">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>


    <div class="container-fluid margin-content">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/games.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>


<!---- games.html START --->

<input type="text" ng-model="searchGame" placeholder="Search for Game" >
<div class = "row" ng-controller = "GamesCtrl">


 <div class = "col-xs-6 col-md-3 well" ng-repeat = "game in games | filter: searchGame">
  <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
   <img style="height:100px"ng-src = "{{game.image}}" alt="{{game.name}}">
  </a>
  <div class = "text-center">{{game.name}}</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class = "col-xs-12">
  <pagination class = "pagination" total-items="games.length" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="pageSize"></pagination>
 </div>
 

</div>

<!---- games.html END --->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed jQuery and bootstrap.js and included dependencies from CDNs don't see the problem.

```js
(function(){

'use strict';

angular.module('ghostApp',['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('GamesCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

   $scope.currentPage = 1;
   $scope.pageSize = 12;

   $http.get("json/games.json").success(function(data){
    $scope.games = data;
   });


  }]);

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ghostApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img class="navbar-brand" src="images/ghost.png"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/home/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/events/">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/games/">Games</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/media/">Media</a>
                    </li>                
                    <li class="page-scroll text-center">
                        <a href="#/about/">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>


    <div class="container-fluid margin-content">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/games.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>


<!---- games.html START --->

<input type="text" ng-model="searchGame" placeholder="Search for Game" >
<div class = "row" ng-controller="GamesCtrl">


 <div class = "col-xs-6 col-md-3 well" ng-repeat = "game in games | filter: searchGame">
  <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
   <img style="height:100px" ng-src="{{game.image}}" alt="{{game.name}}">
  </a>
  <div class = "text-center">{{game.name}}</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class = "col-xs-12">
  <pagination class = "pagination" total-items="games.length" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="pageSize"></pagination>
 </div>
 

</div>

<!---- games.html END --->
```